# Problem using graphics.h in Ubuntu

Tags: graphics, c++

```
# include<stdio.h>
# include<graphics.h>
# include<math.h>
using namespace std;
int main(void)
{
    int gd=DETECT,gm;
    int r,x,y,p,xc=320,yc=240;

    initgraph(&gd,&gm,NULL);
    cleardevice();


    printf("Enter the radius ");
    scanf("%d",&r);


    x=0;
    y=r;
    putpixel(xc+x,yc-y,1);

    p=3-(2*r);

    for(x=0;x<=y;x++)
    {
        if (p<0)
        {
             y=y;
            p=(p+(4*x)+6);
        }
        else
        {
            y=y-1;

            p=p+((4*(x-y)+10));
        }

    putpixel(xc+x,yc-y,1);
    putpixel(xc-x,yc-y,2);
    putpixel(xc+x,yc+y,3);
    putpixel(xc-x,yc+y,4);
    putpixel(xc+y,yc-x,5);
    putpixel(xc-y,yc-x,6);
    putpixel(xc+y,yc+x,7);
    putpixel(xc-y,yc+x,8);

    }
    getch();
    closegraph();
}
```

- installed graphics.h
- compiled using `gcc filename.cpp -0 filename -lgraph`
- then used `./filename`
- the window apperared for 10 seconds and the error below appears:

```
[xcb] Unknown sequence number while processing queue
[xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called
[xcb] Aborting, sorry about that.
heart: ../../src/xcb_io.c:273: poll_for_event: Assertion `!xcb_xlib_threads_sequence_lost' failed.
Aborted
```

Any solutions?

Comment: Would you mind posting the source code somewhere, so that one can try compiling that and diagnose the problem?

Comment: did you try calling `XInitThreads();` as the first code at main()?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [bug filed in Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/930004) very similar to the above problem.

One [message](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/930004/comments/9) contains a quote from the source detailing when this error condition occurs:

> The error message "Unknown sequence number while processing queue"
>   occurs in a chunk of text that has this big fat warning in front of
>   it, about threading safety in client code:
>
> ```
> /* Thread-safety rules:
>  *
>  * At most one thread can be reading from XCB's event queue at a time.
>  * If you are not the current event-reading thread and you need to find
>  * out if an event is available, you must wait.
>  *
>  * The same rule applies for reading replies.
>  *
>  * A single thread cannot be both the the event-reading and the
>  * reply-reading thread at the same time.
>  *
>  * We always look at both the current event and the first pending reply
>  * to decide which to process next.
>  *
>  * We always process all responses in sequence-number order, which may
>  * mean waiting for another thread (either the event_waiter or the
>  * reply_waiter) to handle an earlier response before we can process or
>  * return a later one. If so, we wait on the corresponding condition
>  * variable for that thread to process the response and wake us up.
>  */
> ```
>
> This seems to suggest perhaps this client application could have some
>   faulty logic in its thread handling as relating to the xcb calls?